# bootstrap 3 skipping not putting all pictures into rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have several pictures but oddly it bootstrap is leaving two blank spots in the row every now and then. Here is an example of one of them:

[image]

Here is the code causing it:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 ">
        <div class="content-panel hovereffect overlay">
            <!-- Content panel in every span for padding -->
            <img height="10" width="10" class="img-responsive content-image" ng-src="assets/img/hobbies/Tel_Aviv.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2></h2>
                <h4 style="color:white;">Tel Aviv, Israel</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 ">
        <div class="content-panel hovereffect overlay">
            <!-- Content panel in every span for padding -->
            <img height="10" width="10" class="img-responsive content-image" ng-src="assets/img/hobbies/turkey.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Istanbul, Turkey</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 ">
        <div class="content-panel hovereffect overlay">
            <!-- Content panel in every span for padding -->
            <img height="10" width="10" class="img-responsive content-image" ng-src="assets/img/hobbies/amsterdam1.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2></h2>
                <h4 style="color:white;">Amsterdam, Netherlands</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I didn't post all the pictures but they all follow the same convention.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code. My guess is that one of your file names is incorrect. Make sure the file type is actually '.jpg' and they are in the folders. Check you cases as well.

Comment: @andnowchris no all 26 pictures are populating.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if you are missing a '</div>' somewhere. I can't be sure without all of the code. Also, why are you switching between h2 and h4 for your captions?

Comment: I figured it out. If was the size of the pictures. I had to move some around. They were all different sizes, something I need to look at changing. I was just trying to resize them with css and html but it caused me issues in the end.

Comment: Nice, I hate it when it's something like that. Pictures can be a developers responsive nightmare. I'm glad you got it figured out though!